# Mysql: Using AGAINST() in a subquery

Tags: mysql

I am doing a `MATCH()` and `AGAINST()` in my select in Order to COUNT data from another table quickly.

for a single string, I can do it with ease:

```
SELECT * from persons WHERE MATCH(full_name) AGAINST('"DOE, JOHN"');
```

Is it possible for `AGAINST()` to contain a column name as a parameter and use `CONCAT()` in order to produce a similar paramater `AGAINST('"DOE, JOHN"');`?

I have tried the query below but it's a no go.

```
 SELECT id,
        full_name,
        citymun_id,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) from other_persons WHERE MATCH(other_persons .full_name) AGAINST(CONCAT('"',persons.full_name,'"')) as person_count
 FROM persons
```

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html says:

> `AGAINST` takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.